# How do I make the correct option lit up green when the wrong answer chosen is shown in red?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a quiz game for Android and I have small problem. When the wrong answer is chosen, the chosen answer must become red and the correct answer must turn green. However, I can't do the last part. The wrong answer does turn red but I don't know how to make correct answer light up green.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class OyunBasladi extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvTimer;
    TextView tvResult;
    ImageView ivShowImage;
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> techList = new ArrayList<>();
    int index;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    TextView tvPoints;
    int points;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    long millisUntilFinished;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_soru1);
        tvTimer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
        tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        ivShowImage = findViewById(R.id.ivShowImage);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        tvPoints = findViewById(R.id.tvPoints);

        index = 0;

        techList.add("Çin");
        techList.add("Türkiye");
        techList.add("Rusya");
        techList.add("D.Kongo Cumhuriyeti");
        techList.add("Mısır");
        techList.add("Kazakistan");
        techList.add("St. Lucia");
        techList.add("Trinidad ve Tobago");
        techList.add("İsviçre");
        techList.add("Lüksemburg");
        techList.add("Tonga");
        techList.add("Filipinler");
        techList.add("Guyana");
        techList.add("Guatemala");
        techList.add("ABD");
        techList.add("Kanada");
        techList.add("Peru");
        techList.add("Burundi");

        map.put(techList.get(0), R.drawable.cin);
        map.put(techList.get(1), R.drawable.turkiye);
        map.put(techList.get(2), R.drawable.rusya);
        map.put(techList.get(3), R.drawable.dkongocumhuriyeti);
        map.put(techList.get(4), R.drawable.misir);
        map.put(techList.get(5), R.drawable.kazakistan);
        map.put(techList.get(6), R.drawable.stlucia);
        map.put(techList.get(7), R.drawable.trinidadvetobago);
        map.put(techList.get(8), R.drawable.isvicre);
        map.put(techList.get(9), R.drawable.luksemburg);
        map.put(techList.get(10), R.drawable.tonga);
        map.put(techList.get(11), R.drawable.filipinler);
        map.put(techList.get(12), R.drawable.guyana);
        map.put(techList.get(13), R.drawable.guatemala);
        map.put(techList.get(14), R.drawable.abd);
        map.put(techList.get(15), R.drawable.kanada);
        map.put(techList.get(16), R.drawable.peru);
        map.put(techList.get(17), R.drawable.burundi);

        Collections.shuffle(techList);

        millisUntilFinished = 10000;

        points = 0;

        startGame();
    }

    private void startGame() {

        millisUntilFinished = 10000;

        tvTimer.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
        tvPoints.setText(points + " / " + techList.size());

        generateQuestions(index);

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimer.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                index++;
                if (index > techList.size() - 1){
                    ivShowImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(OyunBasladi.this, OyunBitti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("points", points);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    countDownTimer = null;
                    startGame();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void generateQuestions(int index) {
        ArrayList<String> techListTemp = (ArrayList<String>) techList.clone();
        String correctAnswer = techList.get(index);
        techListTemp.remove(correctAnswer);
        Collections.shuffle(techListTemp);
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(techListTemp.get(0));
        newList.add(techListTemp.get(1));
        newList.add(techListTemp.get(2));
        newList.add(correctAnswer);
        Collections.shuffle(newList);
        btn1.setText(newList.get(0));
        btn2.setText(newList.get(1));
        btn3.setText(newList.get(2));
        btn4.setText(newList.get(3));
        ivShowImage.setImageResource(map.get(techList.get(index)));
    }

    public void nextQuestion(View view) {
        btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"));
        btn2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"));
        btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"));
        btn4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3"));
        btn1.setEnabled(true);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        btn3.setEnabled(true);
        btn4.setEnabled(true);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        index++;
        if (index > techList.size() - 1){
            ivShowImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(OyunBasladi.this, OyunBitti.class);
            intent.putExtra("points", points);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            countDownTimer = null;
            startGame();
        }
    }

    public void answerSelected(View view) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e"));
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn3.setEnabled(false);
        btn4.setEnabled(false);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        String answer = ((Button) view).getText().toString().trim();
        String correctAnswer = techList.get(index);
        if(answer.equals(correctAnswer)){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
            points++;
            tvPoints.setText(points + " / " + techList.size());
            tvResult.setText("Doğru");
        }
        else
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
            tvResult.setText("Yanlış");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where you make the correct answer green and the wrong answer red. What should I write here so that when the wrong answer is chosen it should show the correct option green meanwhile the wrong answer still being red?

```
    public void answerSelected(View view) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e"));
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn3.setEnabled(false);
        btn4.setEnabled(false);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        String answer = ((Button) view).getText().toString().trim();
        String correctAnswer = techList.get(index);
        if(answer.equals(correctAnswer)){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
            points++;
            tvPoints.setText(points + " / " + techList.size());
            tvResult.setText("Doğru");
        }
        else
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
            tvResult.setText("Yanlış");
        }
    }
```

The XML Codes

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e8f4f8"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sayac" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="10s"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/yildiz" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPoints"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="0/18"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bu Hangi Ülke?"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivShowImage"
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/android" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#2196f3"
            android:onClick="answerSelected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#2196f3"
            android:onClick="answerSelected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#2196f3"
            android:onClick="answerSelected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#2196f3"
            android:onClick="answerSelected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#2196f3"
            android:onClick="nextQuestion"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Sıradaki"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: it seems that there is a problem in this piece of code if(answer.equals(correctAnswer)){}

Comment: The app works. Its just that I dont know what to write to make the correct answer also light up along with the wrong answer

Comment: Please share your xml file so that we can figure out the layout and views.

Comment: I added the XML file of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model class for storing a question.

```java
public class Question {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> options;
    private String correctAnswer;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }
    public void setOptions(ArrayList<String> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
    public void setCorrectAnswer(String correctAnswer) {
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

And then in your generate questions method you should create a list of the model class instead of the list of strings.

```java
Question question = new Question();

question.setName("What is the capital of France?");
question.setOptions(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Madrid")));
question.setCorrectAnswer("Paris");

ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList();
questions.add(question);
```

And you should keep track of the index of the current question displayed.

int currentQuestion;
In the countdown timer you could increase the index to change the question displayed.

And I can't see where the **answerSelected** is being called but you should modify it so that it can take in the index as a parameter as well.

```java
 public void answerSelected(View view,int indexOfQuestionSelected) {

//getting the current question by the index from the array list of questions.
        Question questionAnswered = questions.get(indexOfQuestionAnswered);
        String answer = ((Button) view).getText().toString().trim();
        
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn3.setEnabled(false);
        btn4.setEnabled(false);

        if(answer.equals(questionAnswered.getCorrectAnswer)){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
            points++;
            tvPoints.setText(points + " / " + questions.size());
            tvResult.setText("Doğru");

        }else{

           String option1 = btn1.getText().toString();
           String option2 = btn2.getText().toString();
           String option3 = btn3.getText().toString();
           String option4 = btn4.getText().toString();
          
           if(option1.equals(questionAnswered.getCorrectAnswer()){

                btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e")); 
            }
            if(option2.equals(questionAnswered.getCorrectAnswer()){
                            
              btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e")); 

            }if(option3.equals(questionAnswered.getCorrectAnswer()){
                            
              btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e")); 

            }if(option4.equals(questionAnswered.getCorrectAnswer()){
                            
              btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17243e")); 

            }
            tvResult.setText("Yanlış");
 
        }
        
      }
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you but I have a question. In the app I made it shows you the photo of the country and you choose from the 4 options. How do I make the photo match along with the correct country?

Comment: @ItzBaturalpPlays you could add a HashMap in the Question data class, that map would map the place name with the imageUrl(or whatever format you have your image in) and also please upvote and accept the answer as a complement to all the effort I put in :)